# My VBA code makes Excel crash every time I run it

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know what line or lines of code keep making my Excel crash every time I run the macro? When I comment out the copying from a different workbook and pasting into the current workbook, it runs fine, so I'm guessing it has something to do with those lines but I don't see why copying and pasting would cause it to crash...

The code is supposed to go through all the files in a folder that are specifically the .xlsb file type and copy a selection from that .xlsb file and paste it into the current .xlsm file.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenFiles()

    Dim objFs As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim file As Object

    Set objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFs.GetFolder(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path)

    Dim lastCol As Integer
    lastCol = 2

    For Each file In objFolder.Files
        If file Like "*.xlsb" Then

            Dim src As Workbook
            Set src = Workbooks.Open(file.Path, True, True)

            src.Worksheets("Rates").Range("C5", "C29").Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(3, lastCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            src.Close False
            Set src = Nothing
            lastCol = lastCol + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Just wondering, why are you incrementing `lastCol`?

Comment: Not quite sure exactly where the issue is, could be a syntax error in your "Set" statement with 'src' or somewhere else. One issue I did notice is in your "pasting" statement. You are missing a period between 'PasteSpecial' and 'xlPasteValues'. Even if that's not the issue, once you fix the other one, that will create a syntax issue for you.

Comment: @Brian looks like he wants to paste in every following column, incrementing it after every paste and using the variable as the column reference in his pasting line

Comment: For starters, a) you cannot select a range on an inactive worksheet, b) you don't need to Select in order to copy, c) why are you saving changes when the only change might possibly be the current selection?

Comment: @MattGaydon - you don't need a period there.

Comment: @MattGaydon - the operation is range.pastespecial paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: @Brian I'm just keeping track of my last column for future purposes.

Comment: Shows how much I know. Thought there was something missing, but looks like everyone learns something now. Listen to much smarter people like @Jeeped as opposed to myself

Comment: d) you should be checking to make sure you aren't trying to reopen the workbook you are running from if it is an .xlsb.

Comment: @Jeeped a) how is it inactive if I open it? b) fixed that c) fixed that

Comment: If there are more than a single worksheet then the ActiveSheet could be Sheet2, not the Rates worksheet. It depends on how it was left. You cannot `Worksheets("Rates").Range("C5", "C29").Select` if Sheet2 is the activeSheet.

Comment: Wouldn't the following work, and work better `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(3, lastCol) = src.Worksheets("Rates").Range("C5")`...and again for `C29`? Copy/Paste is expensive.

Comment: @Jeeped how could I ensure that Rates is the active sheet?

Comment: I wouldn't bother. I'd just use `src.Worksheets("Rates").Range("C5", "C29").Copy` possibly putting the Destination parameter to use and discard Application.CutCopyMode = False and Selection.Copy.

Comment: @Brian - `Range("C5", "C29")` is the same as `Range("C5:C29")`, you are thinking of (push to new line) `Range("C5, C29")`.

Comment: @Jeeped Yes, I was. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the Dim out of the loop, check to ensure you're not trying to reopen ThisWorkbook and transfer values instead of copying with the clipboard.

```
...
Dim src As Workbook

For Each file In objFolder.Files
    If file Like "*.xlsb" and file not like ThisWorkbook.name Then

        Set src = Workbooks.Open(file.Path, UpdateLinks:=True, readonly:=True)

        with src.Worksheets("Rates").Range("C5:C29")
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(3, lastCol).resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .value
        end with

        src.Close False
        Set src = Nothing
        lastCol = lastCol + 1
    End If
Next file
...
```